# Nikon D200 Auto Bracketing guidance

Tags: nikon

Is there a good Nikon resource for explaining how to use after setting up the bracketing?  Do I set the shooting to single or continuous? If it's on continuous would it stop after the bracketing is over or does it continue on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-manual :)

**Seriously, read the few paragraphs in the manual that tell you how to activate that feature first.**

IIRC you can assign one of the buttons in the front to activate bracketing and speed up access.

Then, you basically specify the number of frames (3-9) and step size (1/3, 1/2, 1) you want. There generally two common reason for using bracketing:

- **To make sure you get the perfect exposure:** Set the set size small, so that you do not miss it because it falls between steps. The number of frames should be set according to how confident you are about the meter.
- **For HDR / Exposure Blending / Simulating a Graduated ND-filter:** You want as large steps as possible to cover the broadest range. The number of frames depends on how contrasty the scene is. The more contrasty, the more frames are needed.

**EDIT** - In response to question edits :)

- **Continuous drive mode lets you shoot the whole bracket continuously and stops after that.** If you are talking portraits, action or anything that is fleeting, that is probably the best mode to use.
- **Single advance mode lets you shoot one image at a time.** If you are taking long exposures where the timing is critical relative to moving objects, people, passing cars, etc, then you should use this one. This applies for HDR too, where you need to make sure no objects are moving in your frame. For long exposures, you can let vibrations settle between each shot to improve sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up bracketing on the D200 is easy. Press and hold the BKT button. Choose the exposure step (0.3, 0.7, 1 stop) with the front dial. Choose the "pattern" (below, above, or around 0) using the rear dial. The top LCD will show a graphic representing the pattern and step.

Reset the bracketing with the rear dial.

Answer (score 0):

The Manual or Thom Hogan's guides are probably the sources I would suggest.

Your other questions:
press and hold the BKT button (upper back left of the camera)
Turn the rear control dial to select number of shots (2 with one below, 2 with one above, or 3, 5, 7, or 9 evenly spaced) and the front control dial to select the distance each shot should be from what the camera metered for the scene (1/3 to 1/1 EV).

I would reccomend continuos, and yes, the camera will stop in continuous mode after the set is complete. To start another set release and then re-hold the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the keys here is that you have to hold the button down for the range of shots to complete. If you press and release, you get one at a time. That, it seems is mentioned nowhere in the literature. If it is, then I missed it.